# How to populate form in nested model when error occurs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Running Rails 3.2.1.

I went through the "Getting started" guide on the Ruby on Rails site.  I have set up a blog post where someone can comment on the posts.

I modified the example to show an error when I enter in comments that don't validate (no name or comment text).

(A post has multiple comments, etc.)

However, how do I have Rails put this problematic comment back in the form, instead of the page?

Here is my create method in the comments controller:

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
  else
    format.html { render 'posts/show' }
  end
end
```

end

Here is my show.html.erb from posts:

```
<%= render @post %>

<h3>Comments</h3>
<%= render @post.comments %>

<h3>Add a comment</h3>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<p>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
 <% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
</p>
```

And here is my comment form partial:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @comment %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :body %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit "Add Comment!" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And here's my comment partial:

```
 <p>
 <strong><%= comment.name %></strong><br />
 <%= comment.created_at.try(:strftime, "on %A, %B %d %Y at %H:%M:%S") %><br />
 <%= simple_format(h(comment.body), :sanitize => true) %>
 </p>
```

Comment: please add your show.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

In your form when you return from an error.

```
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
              <div id="errorExplanation">
                <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
                <ul>
                <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Same error: Showing /home/dave/cms/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
2:  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
3:               <div id="errorExplanation">
4:                 <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
5:                 <ul>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/show.html.erb